# What to consider on app updates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, updates

I wonder if there is any kind of good documentation or tutorial for what to consider when updating an iOS app to a new version? I think especially of the following questions:

- Updating version & build numbers: Is there anything to consider or is it just to increase the numbers in Xcode?
- Is there any possibility to run specific code (updating methods) on the update or after the first launch of the update (e.g. if the data model has changed or if the user's data has to be updated)? How can this be tested in simulator or on testing devices?
- Core Data: What about updating the model in Core Data? How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do my updates I usually:

- prepare the update in iTunes connect
- update version/build in xcode
- for specific update code I simply do in appdelegate - didfinishlaunchwithoptions:

  if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"updateV31"])
  {
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"updateV31"];
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
          //your code here
  }
- for core data, you can use the lightweit migration method, I didn't have issues so far after updates
- for tests, download the current version from the appstore, then add the new version from xcode to your device, it will come as an update over existing app

Comment: thanks. so your upgrade code depends on the version number saved to the user defaults. Isn't there any system-based possibility to run updating code? And for the testing with downloading from app store: this will work only on devices? Update testing on the simulator will not work?

Comment: it's just a trick, actually I store a bool to nsuserdefaults and that will assure the code will run only once. Nsuserdefaults keys are persistent in sandbox trough updates. You can do it with the simulator as well, the only think is you can't download from appstor to your simulator, so basically you need to deploy original version, then the new version to your simulator.

Comment: I just read that Apple recommends NOT to run the new version from Xcode. You should build an ad hoc version instead and sync it with iTunes, as Xcode only pushes changed files into the app: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011323